# ARCGIS featureCluster is not working with points graphics

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, graphics, cluster-analysis, arcgis

(this is a code snippet from an Ionic/Angular project)
I have a database where i store about 60k asteroids with some properties(like name, latitude, longitude). I started making a 3d globe and display a point for every asteroid depending on the lat and long which works fine. I now want to cluster these points to increase performance and added the `featueReduction` property as you can see in my code:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.initGlobe()
  }

  async initGlobe() {
    esriConfig.apiKey = "SomeAPIKey";
    const loading = await this.loadingcontroller.create();
    await loading.present();
    this.map = new Map({
      basemap: "arcgis-imagery"
    });

    this.view = new SceneView({
      container: "viewDiv",
      map: this.map
    });


    await this.view.when(() => {
      console.log("map loaded")
      loading.dismiss();
      StatusBar.setStyle({style: Style.Dark});
      SplashScreen.hide();
    })
  }


  async loadPoints() {

    const simpleMarkerSymbol = {
      type: "simple-marker",
      color: [226, 119, 40],  // Orange
      outline: {
        color: [255, 255, 255], // White
        width: 1
      }
    };


    const loading = await this.loadingcontroller.create();
    await loading.present();
    this.databaseService.getAllAsteroids().subscribe(res => {
      this.allAsteroids = this.databaseService.mapToAsteroids(res.values);

      let graphics = this.allAsteroids.map(function (asteroid) {
        return new Graphic({
          geometry: new Point({
            latitude: asteroid.reclat,
            longitude: asteroid.reclong
          }),
          symbol: simpleMarkerSymbol
        });
      });



      let featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
        source: graphics,
        renderer: new SimpleRenderer({
          symbol: new SimpleMarkerSymbol({
            color: "#102A44",
            outline: {
              color: "#598DD8",
              width: 2
            }
          })
        }),
        objectIdField: "ObjectID",
        fields: [
          {
            name: "ObjectID",
            alias: "ObjectID",
            type: "oid"
          },
          {
            name: "address",
            alias: "address",
            type: "string"
          }
        ],

//I ADDED THIS TO CLUSTER THE POINTS
        featureReduction: {
          type: "cluster",
          clusterMinSize: 16.5,
          // defines the label within each cluster
          labelingInfo: [
            {
              deconflictionStrategy: "none",
              labelExpressionInfo: {
                expression: "Text($feature.cluster_count, '#,###')"
              },
              symbol: {
                type: "text",
                color: "white",
                font: {
                  family: "Noto Sans",
                  size: "12px"
                }
              },
              labelPlacement: "center-center"
            }
          ],
        }
      });



      this.map.layers.add(featureLayer);

      loading.dismiss();
      StatusBar.setStyle({style: Style.Dark});
      SplashScreen.hide();

    })
  }
```

However, its not changing anything. either way my globe looks like this:

[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL7Qn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aPhN.png)

from package.json:

```
"@ionic/angular": "^6.1.9",
"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
"@types/arcgis-js-api": "^4.26.0"
"@arcgis/core": "^4.26.5",
```

Thank you for the help :)

I tried to add `featureReduction` and expected basic clustering

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same Problem: featureReduction is not available for sceneViews (They planned to add it but its not added yet). I have simply overseen it in the docs. So either convert your sceneView to a mapView or write your own clustering function.